# How to use the force-ssl flag correctly with nginx terminating SSL

Tags: ssl, proxy, nginx, meteor

I have meteor behind nginx - nginx is listening to 443. If i set force-ssl to true in meteor, the manual recommends to "set the standard x-forwarded-proto header for the force-ssl package to work."

Does this mean I have add proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; in my nginx config?

And what exactly does this protect me against when I already have add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000; and add_header X-Frame-Options DENY; in my nginx.conf?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment meteor behind nginx might not be a good idea if its for multiple meteor instances as they can't share client's state until they release their DDP proxy. But if its a single instance as per the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#forcessl) you have to set that header in your nginx config.

This only ensures that if meteor is loaded without SSL it forces the browser to use SSL. If you already have a nginx setting that does this for you the force-ssl package won't really do much extra for you.